# convert binary to hex in assembly 80x86

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, converters

I'm looking for a program that coverts a String of 1's and 0's to hexadecimal  string in assembly, where the binary string comes from a code that I write in 'C'.
 for example:

```
10111111100-> "5 F C"
```

The problem is that for more than 12 chars input , the output is wrong , and my mission demands at most 32 chars.

for example given 110010101111-> "CAF"  it works ok!
but giving 10010001101000101011001111000 should be "12345678"
but i only get "123"
debugging with gdb tool i see that the values are being override . how to take care of this with minimal changes in the code? Thanks

The idea is to transform the string pointed by ecx to a value in eax.
now i want to take the 4 most right each time and convert them , and them put them in edx .

So far, I have:

```
section .rodata
LC0:
  DB    "The result is:  %s", 10, 0 ; Format string

section .bss

LC1:
  RESB  32

section .text
  align 16

  global my_func
  extern printf

my_func:
  push  ebp
  mov   ebp, esp            ; Entry code - set up ebp and esp
  pusha                   ; Save registers
  mov ecx, dword [ebp+8]    ; Get argument (pointer to string)
  mov ebx, 0              ; counter for length
  mov eax, 0              ; will hold the string as a value
  mov edx, 0              ; manipulation helper
  mov edi, 0              ; counter for ehile_length loop

length:
  inc ebx
  cmp byte [ecx+ebx], 0x00
  jne length
  dec ebx

;;;;THIS PART IS PARSING THE STRING INTO A REGISTER;;;

bring_ecx_to_end:
  inc ecx
  cmp byte [ecx], 0x0
  JNE bring_ecx_to_end
    dec ecx
    dec ecx
    or edi ,ebx
    add esi,1

while_length:
  mov  dl,byte [ecx]      ; gets 1 char into edx
  cmp DL, 0x31            ; the right character
  JE inc1                 ; if it  a '1'    

resume_loop:
  shl esi,1 ; multiply by 2
  dec ecx
  sub edi,1
  cmp edi,0
  jne while_length

;;;;;;;;;;NOW EAX CONSISTS THE STRING ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

mov dword edx,0 ;target register


    while:
        mov dword edi ,0
        add edi ,15 ; masking

        and edi,eax
        cmp di , 10
         jl less_than_10

      ;less_than_F
          add di ,55    
          jmp resume

    less_than_10:
     add di ,48

 resume:    
     or edx,edi
     shl edx,8
     shr eax,4
     cmp al ,0
      jne while

      shr edx , 8

;;;;;;;;;DONE;;;;;;;;;;;;;

end:
  mov dword [LC1],edx

  push LC1                ; Call printf with 2 arguments: pointer to str
  push LC0                ; and pointer to format string.
  call printf
  add esp, 8              ; Clean up stack after call

  popa                    ; Restore registers
  mov   esp, ebp            ; Function exit code
  pop   ebp
  ret

inc1:   
  or eax, esi
  jmp resume_loop
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code correctly. Editing help can be found under the `(?)` button in the toolbar.

Comment: ..  In addition, do not say "it does not work". **Explain** how it does not work.

Comment: i apologize i fixed it , hope its ok :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the task to convert a **string** of zeroes and ones into a **string** of hexcharacters ("10111111100" -> "000005FC") then the first thing to do is to put the value of the source string in a register. 
You need to setup ECX to point to the string *LC1*.

```
mov ecx,[ebp+8]  ;Pointer to an ASCIIZ string of zero and one characters.
xor ebx,ebx
First:
rcl ebx,1
mov al,[ecx]
inc ecx
shr al,1
jnz First
mov ecx,LC1  ;Buffer to recieve 8 hexcharacters.
Again:
rol ebx,4
```

You can simplify the code `shl al,4` `shr al,4` to `and al,15`.

```
end:
shr ebx, 4
inc ecx                             ; increment pointer
cmp byte [ecx], 0                   ; check if byte pointed to is zero
jnz while_ebx_not_zero              ; keep looping until it is null
```

The *end* part should not change EBX and jump back 8 times precisely.

```
end:
inc ecx
cmp ecx,LC1+8
jb Again
```

Comment: hey , what is LC1? i didnt write all the code by myself its a part of a template  that i cant change. so i dont understand "mov ecx ,LC1"  ,"cmp ecx, LC1+8 " Thanks

Comment: LC1 is the address of the 32 bytes buffer that you defined in the .BSS section.

Comment: It's entirely possible that I misinterpreted the question. Is it the task to convert a **string** of zeroes and ones into a **string** of hexcharacters?  ("10111111100" -> "5 F C")

Comment: Hey I RE edit my code , so now i get the answer , but reversed how can i make it stright?

Answer (score 2):

Syntax, gotcha.  (Everybody on earth has done this, including me a zillion times.)

```
cmp al , 00001001    ;This is actually one thousand and one
jz case1001to9       ;but you treat it like it's nine
```

I can't tell if you're using *Masm/Tasm/Nasm/* or whatever, but I believe that if you put the letter "`b`" at the end of your binary numbers, Masm will recognize them as such.

(ooops, edit: The letter `B` at the end is old school.  Just checked [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552157(v=vs.85).aspx) on the Microsoft website and the new improved (no it isn't, but I don't get to vote) way to do this is to insert "`0y`" as a **prefix** instead of my originally suggested "`B`" as a suffix.)

Put my words to the test: before you do this, look at the output from the assembler, and see if the `00001001` is actually a nine or if it is a thousand and one.

If you can't see the output in assembler, step it through debug.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for paying attention to that. i fixed it. But i think the problem is more about the logic of what ive done , i dont really understand how to deal with the string i have in ecx. i'm just trying to take a quarter every time and make it hex , but when i run it ther is no answer , i mean the buffer is empty.

Comment: additionaly im using NASM

Answer (score 1):

Another variant for any-length input. The code is 16-bit and probably could be optimized a bit. Written on a knee, to show the idea

```
mov si, input_string
mov di, output_string
mov ax, 7           ;input_string length
call bin2hex

bin2hex:
  add si, ax        ;si points to the end of input string
  mov bx, ax
  mov cx, 4         ;\
  div cl            ;
  cmp ah, 0         ;compute how many nibbles to convert
  jz short .a       ;and point di to the end of the result buffer
  inc di            ;
  mov ah, 0         ;
 .a:                ;
  add di, ax        ;/
  mov [di], ah      ;terminating zero
 .next_nibble:
  mov cl, 4         ;iterate 4 times
  mov dl, 0
 .next_bit:
  dec si
  mov al, [si]
  shr al, 1         ;mov bit0 to carry flag
  rcl dl, 1         ;shift with carry flag into the least-significant bit
  dec bx
  jz short .stop    ;end of input string?
  dec cx
  jnz short .next_bit
 .stop:
  shl dl, cl        ;complete last nibble to full
  cmp dl, 0x0a
  jl short .to_ascii
  add dl, 7         ;0Ah - 0Fh = ASCII codes 41h - 46h
 .to_ascii:
  add dl, 0x30
  dec di
  mov [di], dl
  test bx, bx       ;end of input string reached?
  jnz .next_nibble  ;continue if not
  ret
```